# DOM: Adding empty element to DOM and page reflowing

Tags: javascript, dom

I want adding elements to DOM while avoid page reflowing.
My questions:

```
var Span = document.createElement('span');
document.body.appendChild(Span);
// Span doesn't contain any child node
// and isn't setted or inherited any style
// so Span has width = height = 0
```

1. Will adding Span to DOM cause page reflowing?

   ```
   // After adding Span to DOM,
   // I need to add style and text to Span.
   // In order to avoid page reflowing, I set style 'display:none' to Span.
   Span.style.cssText = 'display:none;other:value';
   Span.textContent = 'some text';
   ```
2. Can I use `style.cssText` property to set `display:none` and other css properties and avoiding page reflowing?
   Or do I have to set `style.display = none` to avoid page reflowing first then use `cssText` to set other properties later?

Waiting for your advice and thanks for reading!

Comment: *"After adding newDiv to DOM...I need to add style and child elements..."* Why not add them *before* appending it to the DOM? *"Can I use `style.cssText` property..."* Why would you use it *at all*? Use the `style` object's specific style properties, before appending to the DOM.

Comment: You could use [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) "Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow"

Comment: I can code like you said but those questions is what I'm wondering and need to understand clearly. Thanks @T.J.Crowder for replying

Comment: @mcuong: That doesn't make a lot of sense. "I realize I could not stab myself in the foot, but I really want to know how to handle stabbing myself in the foot."

Comment: I have edited questions, changed DIV to SPAN :), thanks for all reply

Answer (score 1):

Adding or changing most things in the DOM will cause reflows.  As suggested by commenters above, the best approach is to build the subtree of elements outside the DOM and then append it all at once:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.style.someStyleProperty = 'someStyleValue'; // repeat as needed
newDiv.innerHTML = 'some tags and text';
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

This will cause a single reflow, at the end when you call `appendChild`.